# Regex Removing Hash from Beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I am running up against a weird problem here. When I run:

```
"#/a/b/c/d".replace("#\/","")
```

I get what I would expect: `a/b/c/d`.

But When I precede this regex with a start of string character `^`, To get:

```
"#/a/b/c/d".replace("^#\/","")
```

This returns the original string `"#a/b/c/d"`.

Could anybody explain why the hash isn't removed and possibly suggest an alternative that would remove the hash only if it appears at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Pass the regex object: `"#/a/b/c/d".replace(/^#\//,"")`

Comment: Regexes have a special syntax with forward slash delimiters, not quotes.

Comment: or `"#/a/b/c/d".replace(RegExp("^#/"),"")`

Comment: Thats awesome, could explain why that works? what is the purpose of the double slash? If you make this an answer I'll accept it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Oh okay, I'm totally on board now. Thanks a million guys!

Comment: @user2662833: I see some one decided to answer a duplicate - please consider accepting/upvoting my answer as you promised. +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a string as the first argument to `.replace()` method, the string is used as a literal and only 1 replacement can be made.

See the [MDN `replace` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> `substr (pattern)`
>   A String that is to be replaced by `newSubStr`. **It is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression.**

What you need is to pass the regex object as the first argument:

```
"#/a/b/c/d".replace(/^#\//,"")
                    ^^^^^^
```

There is no point in using a constructor notation (`RegExp("^#/")` since the pattern is not built dynamically from variables.

*There are no double slashes in the pattern!* The outer `/.../` are called regex delimiters. Then, what is insde is a *pattern*. The pattern is `^#/`, but since the `/` are used as regex delimiters, the `/` in the pattern must be escaped to match a literal `/` (only in the regex literal notation).

Comment: Thanks for that :) I found that really helpful

Comment: Another way too: `name = (name.charAt(0) === '#') ? name.slice(1) : name;`

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `replace` can be either a string or a regular expression.

You are passing a string, so it is looking for an exact match for that string.

Pass a regular expression instead.

```
"#/a/b/c/d".replace(/^#\//,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace` takes as its first argument either a string or a regexp. If you give it a string, it is **not** interpreted as or converted to a regexp; it is treated literally. Therefore, when you add `^` to your string, it replaces nothing, since there is no `^` in the input.

As explained in the comments, you can either pass a regexp literal (`/.../`) as the first argument, or you could construct a regexp with `new RegExp` (but why would you do that?).